# Jenkins Pipeline without using Github on Windows

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-pipeline

Can you use Jenkins Pipeline without using Github and in Windows? Everything I'm seeing leads me to believe the answer to that would be no, but I have been unable to find a definitive answer.

**GOAL:**

I'm wanting to run individual test.xml files in parallel and came across this plugin, however, I'm not so sure Pipeline will work for what I'm wanting.

Currently I just have one Mavaen Build per test.xml file.

```
clean install test -DsuiteXmlFile=RoundTrip.xml -DenvironmentParam="$ENVIRONMENTPARAM" -DbrowserParam="$BROWSERPARAM"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins "Pipeline" is just another one plugin, providing DSL to write your build job logic. That's not a silver bullet anyhow.

I cannot think how it's related to Windows, and, especially, GitHub, it has nothing to do with it.

You can simply install Jenkins on your Windows box, then install pipeline plugin via Jenkins management UI (Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins).

You'll be able to write required pipeline job script in place, without any SCM service engaged.
Whether it will be OS-agnostic or not depends only on pipeline job code you write

Comment: That's encouraging to hear. I already have Jenkins 2.25 up and running and working for individual mvn builds, but every piece of example code I see for the Pipeline plugin contain connections to GitHub. I don't know how to write (or even read, for that matter) Groovy nor DSL. I will dig deeper into trying to learn it, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't going to spin my wheels for something I wouldn't even be able to utilize. Thanks

Comment: Considering you've got Jenkins and 'Pipeline' plugin installed, you should proceed with 'Jenkins > New Item', create Pipeline job there. Pipeline job defaluts to "Pipeline script" mode, so that you enter can enter code directly (alternatively it can pull job script from SCM, guess that confused you)